# How do I translate this unsupported LINQ query to its native Mongo equivalent?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, nosql

I have this chained LINQ query which MongoDB fails to execute:

```
RoleCollection.AsQueryable().Where(r => r.Users.Any(id => id == user.Id))
    .Select(r => r.Name).ToArray();
```

This results in the following error:

```
Any is only support for items that serialize into documents. The current serializer is ObjectIdSerializer and must implement IBsonDocumentSerializer for participation in Any queries.
```

How can I translate the query into a native query which Mongo will support?

Comment: Have you tried `FirstOrDefault` or `Where` with MongoDB, `RoleCollection.AsQueryable().Where(r => r.Users.Where(id => id == user.Id).Count() > 0)` or `RoleCollection.AsQueryable().Where(r => r.Users.FirstOrDefault(id => id == user.Id) != null)`

Comment: @sa_ddam213 They fail as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the following query working, although I'm not entirely certain as to its semantics yet:

```
RoleCollection.Find(new QueryDocument("Users", user.Id))
            .Select(r => r.Name).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to replace `.Any()` with a combination of `.Where()` and a length check, like so:

```
RoleCollection.AsQueryable().Where(r => r.Users.Where(id => id == user.Id).Length > 0)
    .Select(r => r.Name).ToArray();
```

Note however that there is a performance implication here since it will pull back *all* of the Users with that `id` to do a length on it.

I'm not sure what Mongo supports (Sorry I'm answering this purely from a [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) perspective), but you could also use a combination of `FirstOrDefault` and perform a `null` check in your where. That might be better since you're only ever expecting one or nothing:

```
RoleCollection.AsQueryable().Where(r => r.Users.FirstOrDefault(id => id == user.Id) != null)
    .Select(r => r.Name).ToArray();
```

Comment: That's true, but I figure I might as well learn to do native Mongo queries since LINQ support seems so incomplete?

Comment: @aknuds1 Sorry, as mentioned in my (updated) answer, I'm answering this purely from the linq perspective. I haven't worked with Mongo so couldn't comment on it's native linq support.

Comment: Case in point, `FirstOrDefault` isn't supported by Mongo in this case. My other attempts also seem to fail :(